# how to retrive label data using jsoup

Tags: java, android, jsoup

```
<label id="myid">some text here</label>
```

How to access `some text here` by using Jsoup in Android Studio?

I tried:

```
Element link = doc.select("myid").first();
mytext = link.text();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `getElementById` like below:

```
Element link = doc.getElementById("myid");
mytext = link.text();
```

Comment: @KaustubhKulkarni, Have you checked that?

Comment: Sir Its working but pasting undesired text.

Comment: Didn't get you, Could you please clear?

Comment: It gives me `some text here`

Comment: Thanks, it's working.

Answer (score 1):

As Md. Asaduzzaman commented above, `getElementById` is the preferable method for your query as it is the simplest.  However, `select` can be used to query for an element by its id, as you were attempting above.

The reason that your code wasn't working is that `select` accepts a [CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) rather than an id.

In order to use `select` for your query, you would need to include a # before "myid" in order to identify that "myid" is an id:

```
Element link = doc.select("#myid").first();
mytext = link.text();
```

You can use `select` to do more advanced querying, such as:

```
Elements elements = doc.select("#myid li");
```

This would query for all the `<li>` elements that are descended from the element with an id of `myid`.  See the [JSoup documentation on selector-syntax](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) for more information.